# Extract multiple <p> text using for loop in Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, for-loop, beautifulsoup

How do I extract all the `<p>` from the following HTML code, using Beautifulsoup in python, see code below that I am trying

**html code:**

```
<div class="text_details">                  
<p>
Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) said: Islam is based on (the following) five (principles):
</p>
<p>  1. To testify that none has the right to be worshipped but Allah and Muhammad is Allah's Messenger (ﷺ).</p>
<p>  2. To offer the (compulsory congregational) prayers dutifully and perfectly.</p>
<p>  3. To pay Zakat (i.e. obligatory charity)</p>
<p>  4. To perform Hajj. (i.e. Pilgrimage to Mecca)</p>
<p>  5. To observe fast during the month of Ramadan.</p>
<p></p>
</div>
```

**Code:**

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
url = "https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/11"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
for pp in soup.find_all(class_='text_details').p:
       print pp.text
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `select` to fetch all child `p` that have `text_details` as a parent.

Like this:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://www.sunnah.com/bukhari/11"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
for pp in soup.select("div.text_details > p"):
    print (pp.text)
```

Answer (score 0):

you should `find`(return one tag) the `div` tag then `find_all`(return a list of tag) the `p` tag

```
In [59]: for pp in soup.find(class_='text_details').find_all('p'):
    ...:     print(pp.text)
    ...:     
I heard Allah's Messenger (ﷺ) (p.b.u.h) saying, "We (Muslims) are the last (to come) but (will be) the 
foremost on the Day of Resurrection though the former nations were given the Holy Scriptures before 
us. And this was their day (Friday) the celebration of which was made compulsory for them but they 
differed about it. So Allah gave us the guidance for it (Friday) and all the other people are behind us in 
this respect: the Jews' (holy day is) tomorrow (i.e. Saturday) and the Christians' (is) the day after 
tomorrow (i.e. Sunday)."
```

The div tag contains only `p` tag, so you can get all the text by:

```
In [60]: soup.find(class_='text_details').text
```